# How to call an rest api with JWT bearer token Authorization in windows application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token

I am new to API, I have to create a service which will upload data to an external api. That api uses clientid,secret_client, username, password, and endpoint url for JWT token. it is using oAuth2.0 and
Request Header and content type as application/xml Header Prefix is Bearer. Grant type is password auth.
In postman first I have to get a token once once authentication completed then I have to use or add this token for my Upload and for stream (which is used to get me the id of the upload which i have done). This token is only valid for 5 min.

Tried few solutions from google but none of them worked.

Comment: Do the same thing like in postman? Get the token add the token in the bearer header in your follow up API calls. If you fail doing so show the failing code.

Comment: `create a service` -> what kind of service? let's say if it's an asp.net core MVC application, then we can use httpclient to send an http request to your API which adding the bearer token into your request header. you'd better to describe what you have now, and what you want to achieve in details. We even don't know whether you are trying to create an asp.net core application, and whether you already had the token in your app or you still require to obtain the token in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the received token to the header, for example:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGc...
... some more header stuff
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).